# storing array data or single record to same column

Tags: php, mysqli

I am inserting array data to database. And using implode function like this

```
$customers = implode(',', $_POST['customer_type']);
```

And inserting data like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers (id, customers) VALUES ('','".$customers."')";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

If i select multiple customers, my insert query works perfect. If I select single customer, then my query doesn't inserts any data to database.

So please suggest me how do i do it?

Comment: Bad database design, you should consider storing them in separate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :-

```
if(is_array($_POST['customer_type'])){
   $customers = implode(',', $_POST['customer_type']);
} else {
   $customers = $_POST['customer_type'];

}
```